# "Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "person_id" while adding this parameter to arguments

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an error from symfony 4 "Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "person_id", already tried options for related questions which I found on stackoverflow, but all of them suggest to solve this with @paramconverter, but this method has something to do with @route, I don't think thats what I need.

Here is the code in controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/skill/new/", name="new_skill")
 * Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Person $person_id
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|Response
 */
public function new(Request $request, Person $person_id) {
    $skill = new Skill();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($skill)
        ->add('name', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
        ->add('level', TextareaType::class, array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')
        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Create',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary mt-3')
        ))
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $skill = $form->getData();
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $person = $entityManager->getRepository(Person::class)->find($person_id);
        $person->addSkill($skill);
        $entityManager->persist($skill);
        $entityManager->persist($person);
        $entityManager->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('skill_list');
    }
    return $this->render('main/new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

and from Person entity

```
class Person
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Skill", mappedBy="person")
 */
private $skills;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->skills = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getName(): ?string
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName(string $name): self
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return Collection|Skill[]
 */
public function getSkills(): Collection
{
    return $this->skills;
}

public function addSkill(Skill $skill): self
{
    if (!$this->skills->contains($skill)) {
        $this->skills[] = $skill;
        $skill->setPerson($this);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function removeSkill(Skill $skill): self
{
    if ($this->skills->contains($skill)) {
        $this->skills->removeElement($skill);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($skill->getPerson() === $this) {
            $skill->setPerson(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

}

With @paramconverter I wrote id param in route like " * @Route("/skill/new/{id}", name="new_skill", but he is giving another error "No route found for "GET /skill/new"

What I am trying to achieve is that when I create new skill it binds to specific person with specific id, so I made ManyToOne assosiation. So, while Im on route "/person/{{ person.id }}", I need to add skill to this specific id, not everyone.

I guess I made a mistake writing person_id on function arguments, but otherwise it cant find this param in entitymanager. How can I solve this?

Comment: I presume you've also set in Entity Skill:

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Person", inversedBy="skills")
     */
    private $person;

right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is inside the Route definition and method signature. Symfony has no way to infer which `Person $person_id` it should fetch. If you want this to be an entity you should assign a url parameter for the id, e.g.

```
@Route("/skill/new/{person_id}", name="new_skill")
```

This will change the URL from http://example.com/skill/new to http://example.com/skill/new/123 where `123` is the id you want to fetch the `Person`-object for. Now you MUST have a person id in your URL otherwise the route will not match (as you have already noticed). You can make this optional by changing the method signature:

```
/**
 * @Route("/skill/new/{person_id}", name="new_skill")
 * Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Person $person_id
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|Response
 */
public function new(Request $request, Person $person_id = null) {
```

By allowing null for `$person_id` the url parameter should be optional, so you should be able to use http://example.com/skill/skill/new or http://example.com/skill/skill/new/123.

If you don't want the entity and only want a way to optionally fetch it from the URL without explicitly specifying route parameter you could just change the code a bit:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/skill/new", name="new_skill")
 * Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param Person $person_id
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|Response
 */
public function new(Request $request) {
    $person_id = $request->query->get('person_id');
    ...
```

If you now take your existing URL and add a URL parameter it will be read in your action, e.g. http://example.com/skill/new?person_id=1234 will set `$person_id` to 1234. When you don't specify the parameter it will be null.

Symfony also has debug commands that help you check what routes there are and whether they match:

```
bin/console debug:router

bin/console router:match /skill/new
```

Comment: Your method is correct, but I found a problem in my code. I guess in controller everything was right, but in my html template, while I click the button it looks like "<a href="/skill/new/{person_id}">Add skill</a>" that probably is not right. I tried to write this way "<a href="/skill/new/{{skill.id}}">Add skill</a>" but the problem is with variable "skill", it only works within "{% for skill in skills %}" but it mustn't be there. How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, if your link specifies that you only pass in one skill id then this is what you end with. You could also pass a comma separated list of ids by using something like `{{ skill_ids|join(',') }}`, where `skill_ids` is a list of ids that you extract from `skills`. In that case you will also have to update your controller action to allow passing multiple ids and then performing the adequate query. Maybe you can write a separate question for the problem that you have when working with multiple ids.